# How to unsubscribe/stop Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I use the following code for timer:

```
export class TimerService {
  private ticks: number = 0;
  private seconds: number = 0;
  private timer;

  constructor(seconds: number) {
    this.seconds = seconds;
    this.timer = Observable.timer(2000, 1000);
    this.timer.subscribe(t => {
      this.ticks = t;
      this.disactivate();
    });
  }

  private disactivate() {
    if (this.ticks === this.seconds) {
      this.timer.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to stop timer in line:

```
this.timer.dispose(); // this.timer.unsubscribe();
```

It does not work for me

Comment: I need to stop timer and fix last timer time in seconds.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `subscribe` method returns a `Subscription` object, which you can later use to stop listening the stream contained by the observable to which you subscribed.

```
import { ISubscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription':
import { TimerObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/TimerObservable';

export class TimerService {
  private ticks = 0;
  private timer$: TimerObservable;
  private $timer : ISubscription;

  constructor(private seconds = 0) {
    this.timer$ = TimerObservable.create(2000, 1000);//or you can use the constructor method
    this.$timer = this.timer.subscribe(t => {
      this.ticks = t;
      this.disactivate();
    });
  }

  private disactivate() {
    if (this.ticks >= this.seconds) {
      this.$timer.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Its important to notice that `unsubscribe` exist in rxjs (version 5 and up), before that, in rx (version lower than 5, a different package) the method was called `dispose`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to unsubscribe when instance is destroyed.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
 this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet worked with the timer yet but I think the concept still works. The approach I used was working with a service.

(the work is based on: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0)

1. Create my `new BehaviorSubject<T>(T)`.
2. Create a `new Subscription()` object.
3. wrap subscriptions with the `addSubscription` method.
4. when the parent or higher component gets destroyed `ngOnDestroy(): void` unsubscribe

**Service**

```
private organisation = new BehaviorSubject<__Organisation>(newOrganisation);
organisation$ = this.organisation.asObservable();

private organisationSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
```

**Service Methods**

```
addOrganisationSubscription(subscription: Subscription): void {
    this.organisationSubscription.add(subscription);
}
unSubscribeOrganisation(): void {
    this.organisationSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

addOrganisationSubscription(subscription: Subscription): void {
   this.organisationSubscription.add(subscription);
}
```

**Component**

```
this.organisationService.addOrganisationSubscription(
      this.organisationService.organisation$.subscribe(
      ...
      )
)

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.organisationService.unSubscribeOrganisation();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So after some PUNISHING research I've added my own npm library for this problem.

`Improves previous answer by NOT having to add any extra convolution variables and ease of use.`

- [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dswrjc)
- [Repo](https://github.com/dontboyle/rxjs-serial-subscription/wiki)
- [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-serializable-subscription)

[image]