# How to destroy an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have established an observable in my service in order to poll for updates from an API every 2 seconds; the observable is persisting but I need to destroy it when I move pages or make a call for a different result.

Can anyone help in how to destroy the observable either on page exit or as a manual request (e.g. from another call to the API)?

```
return Observable.interval(2000).switchMap(() => {
  return super.doRequest('/audit/api/' + this.API_version + '/Query/GetFlowHistory?sagaId=' + sagaId, 'get', {}).map((responseData) => {

    return responseData
  }); })
```

Comment: What if you unsubscribe from it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unsubscribe/stop Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233534/how-to-unsubscribe-stop-observable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `takeUntil` from RxJS. takeUntil will stop subscription. 
See the example below.

```
class myComponent {
  private destroyed$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  ngOnInit() {
    return Observable.interval(2000).switchMap(() => {
      return super.doRequest('/audit/api/' + this.API_version + '/Query/GetFlowHistory?sagaId=' + sagaId, 'get', {}).map((responseData) => {
        return responseData
      });
    }).takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  }

  destroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next(true);
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: great suggestion thank you very much! especially the relevant example